# Is FIDE still using the same logo for world championship final?

Tags: history, world-championship

I remember that this logo was used last championship, why are they still using it? Shouldn't every final have its own logo? Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure? I don't remember seeing it, and googling I couldn't find a source from 2016 with that logo. Here's the one that I found:

[image]

Comment: Ahh perhaps it's my mistake, I remember seeing it long time ago, I thought I saw it in 2016, turns out I saw it in 2017 https://www.bbc.com/news/world-42425587, this is the article I read